# Unable to get JavaScript functionality to work in any browser besides Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficulty getting some JavaScript features to work in any other browser besides Firefox. I tried Chrome, Safari, IE and they all seem to produce a similar pattern of problems. In particularly when you click each one of the colored bars (try it in Firefox and it'll work properly), the containers do not open.

My site: http://crossborders.tv/client/frisbie/brian/

Comment: Post your relevant code, don't just supply links.

Comment: Please post a relevant snippet of your code here so future viewers can see the problem and its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of javascript errors on that page. Use developer tools in Chrome to debug these errors. The one that I'm getting that is most likely your problem is on these pieces of code.

```
$('.content').not(content).slideUp(400, 'linear'); //line 78 frisbie.js
$('.content').not(content).slideUp(400, 'linear'); //line 97 frisbie.js
```

The variable, `content`, that you're using in the `.not()` is not defined.

Looks like you're probably wanting `$content` for line 97. For line 78, there is no variable in scope that resembles content, at least as far as I can tell from glancing at your code.

Comment: I think @BHNYC meant to use `window.content` instead of `$content` in that case. `content` in FFX is an "alias" to `window.content`, but this doesn't "work" in other browsers I guess.

Comment: Ah, didn't even think of that, even I learned something. :)

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox, `content` is an "alias" to `window.content`.

Instead of doing ...

```
$('.content').not(content).slideUp(400, 'linear');
```

... call

```
$('.content').not(window.content).slideUp(400, 'linear');
```

Problem solved. :)